# How to access iPhone application directory and store image files there

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to know whether I can access the directory where my application is installed.
Also I want to create a sub directory in the same directory to store all the images I capture in my application. I further want to view the images using iPhone's default image viewer. Can this be done?

Answer (score 14):

```
NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  
NSLog(@"App Directory is: %@", appFolderPath);
NSLog(@"Directory Contents:\n%@", [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: appFolderPath]);
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's question at all.

Comment: This will give the name of app bundle folder which is not writable.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the Document folder of the app

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
```

You can create Folder and files using NSFileManger. You can store files in document folder or even you can store it in temp folder.

Comment: Do you mean NSApplicationDirectory instead of NSDocumentDirectory?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the app on the simulator, navigate to this directory:

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications

If you want to access the app on a device it gets a little trickier. First, plug your iOS device into iTunes and backup the phone (with encryption turned off). Then download this app: [iPhone / iPod Touch Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com/), find your bundle ID and click extract. The app will then get all the data for you to see. Sure it's not real time but does the job!

Answer (score 1):

~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
[link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/120-Running_Applications/running_applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

To store any files of your own, you'll have to use the Documents directory as Girish already said. But if you need to display images that you captured using the camera, the only way you can display them with UIImagePickerController (the default image viewer) is by specifying the source type when initializing it as the saved photos album.

Answer (score -11):

C'mon, this is all in the sample code and documentation. In fact, it's even one of the Frequently Asked Questions in the iPhone Dev Center. I refuse to give the answer. Instead, here's a link:
[Easily found documentation that answers your question](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/DataManagement/index.html)

Comment: This is still getting up votes?  Ugh.  The answer is nowhere to be found on the link you provided.  I spent 15 minutes looking for this answer as well.  RTFM is not a valid answer, this is a legitimate question.

Comment: @pjb3 - it is there in the link read carefully. you may find it under title "File Management"

Comment: How do I write information locally?

You can write to your application's local storage area. You find the path by calling the Foundation function NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains. For more information, see "Getting Paths to Application Directories" in